# Panoramic ImageView in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have implementation for panoramic view which was working great until i switched to ConstraintLayout instead of RelativeLayout. Now i am having problems that ImageView centre panoramic image left edge to left edge of device instead of centre image to current visible screen, so basically when my gyro rotates to left its black and when i go max right image is cut.

Previously i had like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and now i have

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any idea what am i doing wrong or how does constraint handle this differently?

Comment: Apparently, nothing is wrong with this approach.

Comment: Yea, but it behaving differently at least with positioning image by default

Answer (score 0):

```
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
```

this is wrong. what happens if you change it to match_parent ?

Comment: Same thing, and match_parent is not supported for ConstraintLayout

Comment: it is on implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'.

what version are you using ?

Comment: Stable version 1.1.3

Comment: well - problem is not occuring on my implementation. I received exact same results in ConstraintLayout as in RelativeLayout.

as for reluctance to use developed version, I sympethise. I tried to avoid them too. But sometimes - there is no other way.